# Adding an empty row wherever there is a data change in 1 column

Tags: formatting, office-js, organization

Whenever I run my script, it's adding a new row in between every row that has data, instead of adding a new row in between the cell information changes

[Initial Data Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYaXq.png)

[Goal Data Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5BXg.png)

Here is the code:

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

```
let sheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
let usedRange = sheet.getUsedRange();
let rowCount = usedRange.getRowCount();

for (let i = rowCount; i > 0; i--){
  let cellData = sheet.getCell(i,0)
  let prevCell = sheet.getCell(i-1,0);
  
  if (cellData == prevCell) {
    continue;
  }

  if (cellData == sheet.getCell(99,99)){
    continue;
  }
  
  if(cellData != prevCell){
    cellData.getEntireRow().insert(ExcelScript.InsertShiftDirection.down);
  }
}
```

}

[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx8sp.png)

Comment: See what happens if you replace the "==" with "===" and the "!=" with "!==".  Also, can you reproduce the problem in the Script Lab tool?